# Android Virtual Device detects wrong screen size?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I fully edit GUI on android editor and run it. Android Virtual Device overlap it on the bottom corner.
I'm using android studio LATEST VERSION

Android Editor

[image]

Android Virtual Device(Nexus_5X_API_28)

[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,640:371"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/header_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,35:55"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/book_cover" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="Buisness Advise for starting a small buisness"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buy_button"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="5$"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/wishlist"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wishlist"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buy_button"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="WishList+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buy"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buy" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rating"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/comment"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buy"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/comment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/style"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rating"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_speaker"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/style"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/comment"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/comment"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_style"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ratinText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="4.5+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="Advices"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/comment"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/comment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/comment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/similarText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="Similar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/style"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/style"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/style" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="In this video, I am designing an Android App's Book Details/Buy Page UI(User Interface) with ConstraintLayout"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/commentText" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I fully edit GUI on android editor and run it. Android Virtual Device overlap it on the bottom corner.

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Could share your xml ?

Comment: Sir i'm trying to add xml code but stackoverflow show some error. I don't know why they not updating it.

Comment: stack overflow show this error.  "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: add some details or just a statement such that not all the post will be code

Comment: ok. Now it's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it by wrapping the xml layout with ScrollView, Please try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,640:371"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,35:55"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Buisness Advise for starting a small buisness"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buy"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="5$"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/wishlist"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wishlist"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="WishList+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buy"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buy" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/comment"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buy"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rating"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/style"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rating"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rating"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/style"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/comment"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/comment"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ratinText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="4.5+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rating"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rating"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rating" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="Advices"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/comment"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/comment"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/comment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/similarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="Similar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/style"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/style"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/style" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="In this video, I am designing an Android App's Book Details/Buy Page UI(User Interface) with ConstraintLayout"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/commentText" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But why their is different between editor size and emulator. ScrollView should be used if their are some extra elements from screen. But in this case, as you can see in pictures their is no element that need to be scroll. The emulator should show it perfectly, without scroll.

Comment: You are hiding layout decorations in your editor, show it and you will see it like emulator. 

To show it click on eye icon and Click on "Show Layout Decorations"

Comment: ok. thank you very much. It is by default hide. I see it first time in my android studio.